# Resize a boolean map

Tags: matlab, boolean, matlab-figure

I have a boolean map, thus an array made just with zeros and ones. It has dimension 512x512 and I need to resize it to 256x256.

If I use Matlab imresize, values will be re-scaled and I will not have anymore only 0 and 1 but also other values which I don't want.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: What should be the value of the remapped array for each of the 2^4 possible values of the corresponding 2x2 window in the original map?

Answer (score 2):

Some possible approaches:

- Discard even-indexed entries:

  ```
  map_resize = map(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
  ```
- Discard odd-indexed entries:

  ```
  map_resize = map(2:2:end, 2:2:end);
  ```
- For each 2×2 block compute the mean and then round to `0` or `1`:

  ```
  map = randi([0 1], 6, 6); % example input
  sz = size(map);
  map_resize = col2im(mean(im2col(map, [2 2], 'distinct'), 1), [1 1], sz/2) >= .5;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
__ = imresize(___,method) specifies the interpolation method used.
```

By default, imresize uses bicubic interpolation.
if im not mistaken 'nearest' should work in this case.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html#inputarg_method

Comment: also i see 2 posibilities. one is to skip every 2nd value, or to round results of resized map to 0/1, which should achieve more accurate results in some cases.